# How can I fill down this function?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function Velocidades() As Integer
    Dim C As Integer
    If Range("D1") = 2 And Range("B1") = "A" Then
        C = 3
    ElseIf Range("D1") = 3 And Range("B1") = "A" Then
        C = 6
    Else
        C = 0
    End If
    Velocidades = C
End Function
```

I have just started with VBA and I need help. I need to fill down a column (one of the cells I write the function on), so the info displayed in each cell of the column is the result of applying the function above to the columns `D` and `B` of the same row, so in row `3` the function should be applied to `D3` and `B3`. The problem I get is that my output is pulling down the value from the cell I write the function on all the way down to the end of the data set.

Comment: show the loop that is iterating

Comment: Is this a User Defined Function (UDF)? If yes, we are missing the beginning of it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you have is a UDF, I *think* what you want is this:

```
Public Function Velocidades(myNumber As Long, myString As String) As Long

Dim C As Long
If myNumber = 2 And myString = "A" Then
    C = 3
ElseIf myNumber = 3 And myString = "A" Then
    C = 6
Else
    C = 0
End If
Velocidades = C
End Function
```

Then, in `D2`, enter: `=Velocidades(D2,B2)` and populate down

[image]